# Automatic Db migration (MysQl)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-migration, flyway, knex.js

I'm doing a project in angular.js and node.js, which have three different environments(development, test and product).Each of them have different database(Mysql).My question is related to database migration,

**At present** Db migration (from development to test/product) is doing in a way

- Compare two database by using db differentiation tools and create a sql file which contains the changes (queries) which needs to execute in to the other data base
- Execute all the queries to the database (test/product) manually

**What i Need:**

I would like to automate these Db migration(above mentioned process) by using any tools in a way

- needs to do the comparison of two databases(dev and product) and also save those changes in to a file and execute these changes in to the database (total Db synchronization) By running codes in command line prompt.

i have read about **flyway** and **knex**. But dont know which tool can be used to achieve my requirements.

Can anyone suggest any free tools that can be used to automate the db migration process, Or any alternate process to achieve these requirements.

Comment: [Tungsten Replicator](https://github.com/vmware/tungsten-replicator) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [MySQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-compare/). This is a commercial tool developed at the company I work for, but is free for non-commercial use.

This [Simple Talk article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/mysql-compare-the-manual-that-time-forgot-part-1/) has more information, including how to automate using the command line. Good luck!